# How to get row indices for a sub part of iris data ( based on specie ) in a list?

Tags: r

Good afternoon ,

Assume we have the following dataset :

```
df=structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 5.1, 4.5, 5, 4.8, 5.1, 
6, 5.5, 6.5), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 3, 3.3, 2.3, 3.5, 3, 3.8, 
2.2, 2.4, 3), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.7, 1.3, 1.6, 1.4, 
1.6, 4, 3.7, 5.8), Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.6, 0.3, 
0.2, 1, 1, 2.2), Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 24L, 42L, 44L, 46L, 
47L, 63L, 82L, 105L), class = "data.frame")

# Output :

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
24           5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5     setosa
42           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa
44           5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6     setosa
46           4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3     setosa
47           5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2     setosa
63           6.0         2.2          4.0         1.0 versicolor
82           5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 versicolor
105          6.5         3.0          5.8         2.2  virginica
```

I´m searching to create a **list** of indices for each specie :

```
Expected output :

L=list(´setosa´=c(1,2,24,42,44,46,47),´versicolor´=c(63,82), ´virginica´=c(105) )
```

For this i splited the dataframe :

```
split(iris,iris$Species)

$setosa
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
24          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5  setosa
42          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3  setosa
44          5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6  setosa
46          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3  setosa
47          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2  setosa

$versicolor
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
63          6.0         2.2          4.0           1 versicolor
82          5.5         2.4          3.7           1 versicolor

$virginica
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
105          6.5           3          5.8         2.2 virginica
```

However , i don't know the function to use for obtaining the indices ( I tried `row.names()`).

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `split` on the `row.names`

```
split(as.integer(row.names(df)), df$Species)
```

-output

```
$setosa
[1]  1  2 24 42 44 46 47

$versicolor
[1] 63 82

$virginica
[1] 105
```

Comment: Yes , it's preferable to get indices as integers : lapply(split(row.names(df), df$Species),as.integer).  Thank you a lot for help :) !

Answer (score 1):

A Tidy solution (just using the full Iris data -- you can swap in your data):

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>%
    rownames_to_column('index') %>%
    group_by(Species) %>%
    summarize(
        rownames = list(as.numeric(index))
    ) %>% 
    deframe()

#> $setosa
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25
#> [26] 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
#> 
#> $versicolor
#>  [1]  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69
#> [20]  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88
#> [39]  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100
#> 
#> $virginica
#>  [1] 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119
#> [20] 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138
#> [39] 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you a lot !